# When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?

Tags: rust

I see that [`std::convert::Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) has an implementation for anything that implements [`std::convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html):

```rust
impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
where
    U: From<T>,
```

In the Rust 1.0 standard library, there are many implementations of `From` while `Into` is only implemented in 3 places. This makes it seem like implementing `From` should be the default. I'm certain that there are times I would want to implement `Into` and not `From`, but I'm not seeing them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

TL;DR: prefer implementing `From`.

---

Interestingly, [the original RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0529-conversion-traits.md) about the [`std::convert`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/index.html) traits suggested the opposite blanket implementation:

```
impl<T, U> From<T> for U
where
    T: Into<U>
```

But on the PR implementing it, [it was changed to the opposite](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23538#issuecomment-85215534):

> Added `From` => `Into` implementation, which makes it possible to add conversions in both directions without running afoul of coherence. For example, we now have `From<[T]> for Vec<T>` where `T: Clone`, which yields the corresponding `Into` going in the other direction -- despite the fact that the two types live in different crates.
>
> I also believe this addresses a few concerns about things implementing `From` instead of `Into`

This last-moment change reflects that `From` and `Into` are basically equivalent. `From` was chosen as the preferred one as it was less restrictive from the "type parameter vs. local type" point of view.

Before [Rust 1.41.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1410-2020-01-30), it wasn't possible to make a `impl<'a, T> Into<Foo> for &'a [T]`, while `impl<'a, T> From<&'a [T]> for Foo` was possible.

The first attempt raised a `E0210`:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
 --> x.rs:3:10
  |
3 | impl<'a, T> Into<Foo> for &'a [T] {
  |          ^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

In the standard library prior to Rust 1.14, there were only two examples of implementing `Into` and not `From`:

- `impl Into<Vec<u8>> for String`
- `impl Into<OsString> for PathBuf`

I think these are the reflexion of the logic of their interfaces. `OsString` implements `From<String>` and `From<T> where T: AsRef<OsStr>`, because they are the natural things you'll want to build a `OsString` from.

However, `PathBuf` still implements `Into<OsString>` as the reverse operation of its `From<OsString>` implementation, but this logic belongs to `PathBuf`, not `OsString`.

Comment: *`PathBuf` still implement `Into<OsString>`* ← this has been fixed in 1.14.0 :D. Nothing impl `Into<*>` in the standard library anymore.