# From trait called inside a generic function

Tags: rust

I am using the `From` trait to convert an `i32` to a structure of my own. I use this conversion in a generic function `do_stuff` that doesn't compile:

```
use std::convert::*;

struct StoredValue {
    val: i32,
}

impl From<i32> for StoredValue {
    fn from(value: i32) -> StoredValue {
        return StoredValue {val: value};
    }
}

/// Generic function that stores a value and do stuff
fn do_stuff<T>(value: T) -> i32 where T: From<T> {
    let result = StoredValue::from(value);
    // .... do stuff and
    return 0;
}

fn main () {
    let result = do_stuff(0); // call with explicit type
}
```

and the compilation error:

```
main.rs:15:18: 15:35 error: the trait `core::convert::From<T>` is not implemented for the type `StoredValue` [E0277]
main.rs:15     let result = StoredValue::from(value);
```

Does it make sense to implement a generic version of `From<T>` for `StoredValue`?

Answer (score 2):

Your generic function is saying, "I accept any type that implements being created from itself." Which isn't what you want.

There's a few things you *could* be wanting to say:

"I accept any type that can be converted into an `i32` so that I can create a `StoredValue`." This works because you know `StoredValue` implements `From<i32>`.

```
fn do_stuff<T>(value: T) -> i32 where T: Into<i32> {
    let result = StoredValue::from(value.into());
    // ...
}
```

Or, "I accept any type that can be converted *into* a `StoredValue`." There is a handy trait that goes along with the `From<T>` trait, and it's called [`Into<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html).

```
fn do_stuff<T>(value: T) -> i32 where T: Into<StoredValue> {
    let result = value.into();
    // ...
}
```

The way to remember how/when to use these two traits that go hand in hand is this:

- Use `Into<T>` when you know what you want the end result to be, i.e from `?->T`
- Use `From<T>` when you know what you have to start with, but not the end result, i.e. `T->?`

The reason these two traits can go hand in hand together, is if you have a  `T` that implements `Into<U>`, and you have `V` that implements `From<U>` you can get from a `T->U->V`.

The Rust std lib has such a conversion already baked in that says, "Any type `T` that implements `From<U>`, than `U` implements `Into<T>`."

Because of this, when you implemented `From<i32> for StoredValue` you can assume there is a `Into<StoredValue> for i32`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I chose to use From because I saw in the documentation that it was preferable to use From instead of Into. Is there any reason for that ?

Comment: @cpichard It's preferable to *implement* `From`, but *consuming* `Into` is often better than consuming `From` since it reads more naturally and allows more conversions than `From`.

Answer (score 1):

To make `do_stuff()` work, it must be possible to convert type `T` into `StoredValue`. So its declaration should be

```
fn do_stuff<T>(value: T) -> i32 where StoredValue: From<T> {
```

**Edit:** I agree with Shepmaster that that should better be

```
fn do_stuff<T>(value: T) -> i32 where T: Into<StoredValue> {
    let result = value.into();
    // ...
```

Since there is a generic implementation that turns `T: From<U>` into `U: Into<T>`, this allows to use both kinds of conversions, those implementing `From` and those implementing `Into`.  With my first version only conversions implementing `From` would work.

Comment: Or (mostly) conversely `T: Into<StoredValue>`. [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423) may have more detail on the difference.

Comment: Thanks ! I understand my mistake now, I didn't think it was possible to add types different than he generic ones in a where clause. That totally makes sense now.

Comment: indeed, where T: Into<StoredValue> feels more readable. Thanks !

Comment: unfortunately `where T: Into<StoredValue>` doesn't compile with this example, it looks like `Into` has to be implemented, too bad.

Comment: Works for me, but you also have to change the following line. (I forgot that, added it now.)