# `T.into()` works but `From::from(T)` does not

Tags: rust

In this following code snippet, `convert` is trying to convert its input to a `Box<Error>`:

```
fn convert<T: Into<Box<Error>>>(input: T) -> Box<Error> {
    input.into() // Compiles
    // From::from(input) // Fails to compile
}
```

It works with `input.into()`, but when using `From::from(T)` it no longer works, it requires `T` to implement `Error`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:3
  |
4 |   From::from(input)
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `T`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where T: std::error::Error` bound
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<T>` for `std::boxed::Box<std::error::Error>`
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Why do the requirements change when using `From` or `Into`? This becomes specially annoying when using the `?` operator:

```
fn convert<T: Into<Box<Error>>>(input: T) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    Err(input)? // Fails to compile
}
```

Is there any way to use the `?` operator properly in these cases, or do I have to resort to manual `match` and `into`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why do the requirements change when using `From` or `Into`?

Even when something implements `Into`, that *doesn't mean it implements `From`*. For example, from the implementor list of [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html):

```
impl<T, U> Into<U> for T 
where
    U: From<T>, 

impl Into<Option<P<PathParameters>>> for AngleBracketedParameterData
impl Into<Vec<Annotatable>> for Annotatable
impl<T> Into<Vec<T>> for ThinVec<T>
impl<T> Into<Vec<T>> for P<[T]>
```

Those last four types do *not* implement `From`, but they do implement `Into`. (Note that these types are actually internal compiler types and it's a bug that we can see them in the docs, but it's a useful demonstration for this case.)

See [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423) for more details about the differences of the two traits.

---

You can instead declare that your generic type implements `From` to use it:

```
fn convert<T>(input: T) -> Box<Error>
where
    Box<Error>: From<T>,
{
    From::from(input) // Fails to compile
}
```

Comment: The converse, however, is true: if `U` implements `From<T>`, then `T` *does* implement `Into<U>` (because of the blanket impl of [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html)). The asymmetry of the relationship can be confusing.

Comment: Oh, I see now, thanks. I assumed the From <-> Into relationship was both ways. It's nice you can place constraints with generics on the right hand side too!

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to write your generics in terms of `From`:

```
fn convert<T>(input: T) -> Result<(), Box<Error>>
where
    Box<Error>: From<T>,
{
    Err(input)?
}
```