# Provide default trait implementation based on trait type parameter

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Given this trait:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::fs::File;

pub trait Asset<D> {
    fn load_data(path: &str) -> io::Result<D>
    where
        D: From<Vec<u8>>
    {
        let file = File::open(path)?;
        let bytes_result: io::Result<Vec<u8>> = file.bytes().collect();

        Ok(D::from(bytes_result?))
    }

    // many more methods...
}
```

the `load_data` method is only available when `D` implements `From<Vec<u8>>`, which makes sense. However, I would like every type implementing `Asset<D>` to have `load_data`, where if `D` implements `From<Vec<u8>>`, then it uses the default implementation. Otherwise, the type would have to implement `load_data` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a *blanket implementation* of the trait for any type that implements `From<Vec<u8>>` instead:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::fs::File;

pub trait Asset<D> {
    fn load_data(path: &str) -> io::Result<D>;

    // many more methods...
}

impl<D> Asset<D> for D
where
    D: From<Vec<u8>>,
{
    fn load_data(path: &str) -> io::Result<D> {
        let file = File::open(path)?;
        let bytes_result: io::Result<Vec<u8>> = file.bytes().collect();

        Ok(D::from(bytes_result?))
    }
}

struct Other;

impl Asset<Other> for Other {
    fn load_data(_path: &str) -> io::Result<Other> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl Asset<f64> for Other {
    fn load_data(_path: &str) -> io::Result<f64> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

---

You probably want to use `Into` instead of `From` (it's the opposite logic as [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812530/when-should-i-implement-stdconvertfrom-vs-stdconvertinto))