# What does the Value::into method from the serde_json crate do?

Tags: rust, serde

This piece of code calls `val.into()` function where `val` is a `serde_json::Value` enum, but I can't find any description of `into` function in the Rust docs.

```
pub fn parse(&self, s: &str) -> Result<RpcObject, ReadError> {
    let val = serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&s)?;
    if !val.is_object() {
        Err(ReadError::NotObject)
    } else {
        Ok(val.into())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) is a trait with the [single method `into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into). `Into` is implemented for every type that implements [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html):

```
impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
where
    U: From<T>,
```

[`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.11/serde_json/enum.Value.html) implements many different versions of `From`

```
impl From<i8> for Value
impl From<i16> for Value
impl From<i32> for Value
impl From<i64> for Value
impl From<isize> for Value
impl From<u8> for Value
impl From<u16> for Value
impl From<u32> for Value
impl From<u64> for Value
impl From<usize> for Value
impl From<f32> for Value
impl From<f64> for Value
impl From<bool> for Value
impl From<String> for Value
impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Value
impl<'a> From<Cow<'a, str>> for Value
impl From<Map<String, Value>> for Value
impl<T: Into<Value>> From<Vec<T>> for Value
impl<'a, T: Clone + Into<Value>> From<&'a [T]> for Value
```

These two traits are used to provide conversions between types that cannot fail. The traits [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) and [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) allow for fallible conversions starting in Rust 1.34.

See also:

- [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423)
- [`From` and `Into` in *Rust by Example*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html)

---

An astute reader will have noticed that what I showed above actually allows you to convert *to* a `serde_json::Value`. Technically, the original code converts to a `RpcObject` *from* a `Value`. Somewhere in your code there is `impl From<serde_json::Value> for RpcObject`, but since that implementation isn't provided, I can't link to any useful documentation for that, but the pattern is the same.

Comment: So implementing `From<U> for V` allows me to use `val.into::<U>()`, where `val` is a `V`. Is it true the other way round? i.e. Does implementing `Into<U> for V` allow me to use `U::from(val)`?

Comment: @saga no; that would cause infinite loops.

Comment: `no; that would cause infinite loops.` Why? Isn't `val.into::<U>()` equivalent to `U::from(val)`?

Comment: Yes, there is a `From<Value> for RpcObject` in the code. The code belongs to `xi-editor`. What I don't understand is why would symmetrical behaviour of `From` and `Into` would cause an infinite loop?

Comment: @saga Because there would be a blanket implementation of `From` that says "go look at `Into`" and a blanket implementation of `Into` that says "go look at `From`". There would be nowhere you could actually implement any conversion logic, and the compiler would just cycle back and forth forever trying to figure out what implementation to use. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=526c991b8d2eb4d7debec73f6c005ec3&version=stable).

Comment: That shouldn't be very hard to resolve. The compiler should first check if there is a native implementation for conversion from one type to the other, and it should check for the other one only if that hasn't been implemented. Am I missing something here? Would it cause any other problem?

Comment: @saga if you believe that you can improve the Rust compiler or language, you are certainly encouraged to do so, especially if you believe it to not be hard! Rust is [open-source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) and also has an [open RFC process](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/). However, I don't know what you mean by "native" implementation, all implementations are the same from my point of view, modulo the orphan rules.