# How should I implement Into for &MyType and &mut MyType without code duplication?

Tags: rust

Here is a toy example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Int {
    v: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Double {
    v: f64,
}

impl Into<Double> for Int {
    fn into(self) -> Double {
        Double {
            v: f64::from(self.v),
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but really I want to implement `Into<Double>` for `&Int` and `&mut Int`. This doesn't work:

```
impl<T> Into<Double> for T
where
    T: AsRef<Int>,
{
    fn into(self) -> Double {
        Double {
            v: f64::from(self.as_ref().v),
        }
    }
}
```

because `trait Into` is not defined in my crate:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::Into<Double>`:
  --> src/main.rs:19:1
   |
19 | / impl<T> Into<Double> for T
20 | | where
21 | |     T: AsRef<Int>,
22 | | {
...  |
27 | |     }
28 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T, U> std::convert::Into<U> for T
             where U: std::convert::From<T>;

error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
  --> src/main.rs:19:1
   |
19 | / impl<T> Into<Double> for T
20 | | where
21 | |     T: AsRef<Int>,
22 | | {
...  |
27 | |     }
28 | | }
   | |_^
```

How should I implement `Into<Double>` for `&Int` and `&mut Int`,
without code duplication like:

```
impl<'a> Into<Double> for &'a Int {
impl<'a> Into<Double> for &'a mut Int {
```

Comment: Simplest solution would be to use macro to generate that code for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want, by implementing [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html) instead of its friend [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html):

```
impl<T> From<T> for Double
where
    T: AsRef<Int>,
{
    fn from(i: T) -> Self {
        Double {
            v: f64::from(i.as_ref().v),
        }
    }
}
```

This way we avoid implementing a trait for a generic parameter (the `for T` part) which is disallowed by orphan rules. `From` and `Into` are linked together with [this awesome blanket impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html#implementors):

```
impl<T, U> Into<U> for T 
where
    U: From<T>,
```

---

However, [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) is not the trait you are looking for here (I think). [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) might be more fitting in your situation:

```
impl<T> From<T> for Double
where
    T: Borrow<Int>,
{
    fn from(i: T) -> Self {
        Double {
            v: f64::from(i.borrow().v),
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the conversion is possible for `Int`, `&Int` and `&mut Int`:

```
fn foo<T: Into<Double>>(_: T) {}

foo(Int { v: 3 });
foo(&Int { v: 3 });
foo(&mut Int { v: 3 });
```

See also:

- [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Lukas is how you should implement this; I would like to add, though, that this limitation of `Into<T>` can also be worked around with a wrapper type, as described by the [docs for the related error, E0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210):

> To work around this, it can be covered with a local type, `MyType`:
>
> ```
> struct MyType<T>(T);
>
> impl<T> ForeignTrait for MyType<T> { } // Ok
> ```

That being said, for your needs you should still use `Borrow` instead of `AsRef`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Wrap<T: Borrow<Int>>(T);

impl<T> Into<Double> for Wrap<T>
where
    T: Borrow<Int>,
{
    fn into(self) -> Double {
        Double {
            v: f64::from(self.0.borrow().v),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let i = Int { v: 0 };
    let d: Double = Wrap(i).into(); // or Wrap(&i) or Wrap(&mut i)
}
```