# How do I write a function that allows me to convert a type T into any Box<B> if Box<T> can be coerced into Box<B>?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write an extension trait that allows me to move any value of type `T` into any `Box<B>`, where `Box<T>` can be coerced into `Box<B>`. My first attempt is the following:

```
trait IntoBox<B: ?Sized> {
    fn into_box(self) -> Box<B>;
}

impl<T, B: ?Sized> IntoBox<B> for T
where
    Box<T>: Into<Box<B>>,
{
    fn into_box(self) -> Box<B> {
        Box::new(self).into()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Ok
    let _: Box<u32> = 42.into_box();

    // Error: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<std::fmt::Display>:
    // std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<&str>>` is not satisfied
    let _: Box<std::fmt::Display> = "Hello World".into_box();
}
```

This code works for regular boxes, but not trait objects. I suspect `Into` is the wrong bound here. What should I use instead?

**Edit:** As explained in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247690/how-can-i-define-a-function-with-a-parameter-that-can-be-multiple-kinds-of-trait) question, this problem can be solved with respect to any number of concrete types `T` by providing a blanket impl for `T: Unsize<U>`. However this does not work in the generic case because the impls would be conflicting:

```
impl<T, B> IntoBox<B> for T
where
    Box<T>: Into<Box<B>>,
{
    fn into_box(self) -> Box<B> {
        Box::new(self).into()
    }
}

impl<T, B: ?Sized> IntoBox<B> for T
where
    B: std::marker::Unsize<T>
{
    fn into_box(self) -> Box<B> {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c9834097a07ece7b0d1dff6d5bebe44e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015 this seems to work with your example. but I think you cannot call `.into_box()` on unsized types then.

edit: oh I just see your additional constraint with the `Box<T>` to `Box<B>` coercion.

Comment: Hmm, if the `Box<T>` -> `Box<B>` conversion happens automatically, maybe I don't need that bound after all.

Comment: you don't need to have `From` implemented if you want to convert a Boxed value to a Trait object.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How can I define a function with a parameter that can be multiple kinds of trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51247690/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Edited, the solution does not work in the generic case.

Comment: Yes, it **cannot** be solved in the generic case because they are overlapping. There is no solution to that, it is a hard constraint of the Rust compiler. It has nothing to do with your specific code.

Comment: You're right. I believe there _might_ exist a solution though if the standard library implemented `From<Box<T>> for Box<U> where U: Unsize<T>`.