# Is there any way of converting a struct to a tuple?

Tags: rust

Given something like this:

```
struct Example {
    a: i32,
    b: String,
}
```

Is there any built-in method or any trait I can implement that will allow me to obtain a tuple of `(i32, String)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any way of converting a struct to a tuple

Yes.

> any built-in method or any trait I can implement

Not really.

---

I'd implement [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html), which is very generic:

```
impl From<Example> for (i32, String) {
    fn from(e: Example) -> (i32, String) {
        let Example { a, b } = e;
        (a, b)
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
let tuple = <(i32, String)>::from(example);
```

```
let tuple: (i32, String) = example.into();
```

See also:

- [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423)

Comment: When you implement `From`, I'm pretty sure you get `Into` for free, btw. So you can do `let tuple: (i32, String) = example.into();`. This is often nice because you can take advantage of type hinting.