# Make an argument generic over tuple structs of a specific shape

Tags: rust

Let's say I have some tuple structs that all have the same shape. Is there any way I can have a function be generic over them as they are, without adding any traits? For example with newtypes:

```
struct A(u8);
struct B(u8);

fn foo<T>(new_u8: T) where
    T: [Constraint saying T is a tuple struct with one field of u8]
{
    println!("{}", new_u8.0 + 1);
}
```

I could then call `foo` with both an `A` and a `B`

I know I do that if I make a trait and then impl on all the structs, but that seems very boilerplate-y.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the underlying use case where something like this is needed? It seems like it would be better to have a single type to represent the `u8`s then. Further maybe even a trait implemented for `(u8, ...)`

Comment: @vallentin It definitely could be. I am trying to do something like "Parse a string into one of many collections of newtypes". So the function look like `fn push_from_str<T>(s: &str, v: &mut Vec<T>) {v.push(T(s.parse().unwrap()))}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to *construct* values of the newtype, not to *access* the field of values, you can use a (neat or weird, judge by yourself) trick: every tuple struct is also a function, called the struct's *constructor*, that takes the field type and returns the newtype. So:

```rust
fn push_from_str<T, Ctor: Fn(u8) -> T>(s: &str, v: &mut Vec<T>, ctor: Ctor) {
    v.push(ctor(s.parse().unwrap()));
}

push_from_str("1", &mut vec, A);
```

I wouldn't recommend doing that in production code, though. Just implement `From`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this is not possible, related to:
[Is there any way of converting a struct to a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194323/is-there-any-way-of-converting-a-struct-to-a-tuple)

I think the best way to do this would be to typedef your specific tuple and then do something like this:

```rust
type Tuple = (u8,);

struct A(Tuple);
struct B(Tuple);

fn foo(new_u8: Tuple) {
    println!("{}", new_u8.0 + 1);
}

fn main() {
    let a = A((0,));
    let b = B((1,));
    foo(a.0);
    foo(b.0);
}
```

It would be nice of `A` could get coerced to `Tuple` without having an into impl but the best I can find is to suffer through having to do `a.0`

Comment: Instead of `Into` then you could use [`impl AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html). First `impl AsRef<Tuple>` for `A` and `B`. Then change `fn foo(new_u8: impl AsRef<Tuple>)`. Now you can easily call `foo(&a)` and `foo(&b)`

Comment: but you'll still have to implement some trait for both `A` and `B` which op specifically doesn't want to do.

Comment: Fair enough, but OP also said they wanted it to be generic, which your solution isn't. So the real answer is, to either not wanting it to be generic, or implementing traits. (Ignore the "cursed" but also amazing solution from Chayim)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Think in term of capabilities, not in term of shapes.**

It's common in C++ to reason in term of *shapes*: templates being duck-typed allow you to manipulate structs as long as they have a certain field with a compatible type, etc... The key word here is *duck-typed*.

In Rust, generics are NOT duck-typed. Or, in CS terms, generics are not *structurally* typed. Instead, they are *nominally* typed, relying on traits which describe not the shape, but the capabilities of a value.

When you ask for a trait which describes the shape of an object, you're essentially asking for a bridge between structural typing (shapes) and nominal typing (traits). This is not wrong per se... but it goes against the philosophy of the language -- using nominal typing is a deliberate choice -- and thus you're setting yourself up for failure.

Instead, you need to work *with* the language, and this means shifting your mindset to think *nominally* not *structurally*.

So, rather than asking about the *fields* of a value, you need to ask about the *operations* available on a value (its capabilities).

If your goal is to convert from/to `u8`, then there are standard traits which should be implemented for that:

- `From` and `Into` for infallible conversion.
- `TryFrom` and `TryInto` for fallible conversion.

Moreover, if you only want to peek inside, you may find `AsRef` and `AsMut` -- though beware those "break" encapsulation.

Have look at `Path` and `PathBuf` in the standard library for example, you'll see many methods taking a `AsRef<Path>` allowing to invoke them with `String`, `&str`, `PathBuf`, etc...

Those conversion/view standard traits are the Rust way to describe capabilities for conversion/view.

And if they're not good enough, you can also create your own traits, eh!

Answer (score -1):

If you have a bunch of structs with the same shape, it suggests that you should maybe pull the type out into an enum tag, and store that alongside the data. Then you just have one (non-generic) function to implement:

```rust
enum Kind {
    A,
    B,
}
struct U8ish {
    val: u8,
    kind: Kind,
}

impl U8ish {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.val + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the thinking out of the box, but it'll be a hard-pass from me here. Tuple structs are commonly used _precisely_ to get a different type -- also called the newtype pattern in some circles -- in order to get strong typing and therefore compile-time errors when passing an `A` where a `B` is expected. Your proposal kills compile-time checks, meh.