# Why is an explicit dereference required in (*x).into(), but not in x.my_into()?

Tags: rust, traits, implicit-conversion, dereference

After reading [method-call expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html), [dereference operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator), [method lookup](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6d91a2bdac45cd919497a24207fab843124d4ba/src/librustc_typeck/check/method/README.md), and [auto-dereferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules), I thought I had a pretty good understanding of the subject; but then I encountered a situation in which I expected auto-dereferencing to happen, when in fact it didn't happen.

The example is as follows.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Foo();

impl Into<&'static str> for Foo {
    fn into(self) -> &'static str {
        "<Foo as Into>::into"
    }
}

fn vec_into<F: Copy + Into<T>, T>(slice: &[F]) -> Vec<T> {
    slice.iter().map(|x| (*x).into()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let array = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()];
    let vec = vec_into::<_, &'static str>(&array);
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

The code above works, but I thought that the explicit dereferencing `(*x).into()` in the function `vec_into` wasn't needed. My reasoning is that, since `x: &Foo`, then `x.into()` would try to find methods accepting type `&Foo`, `&&Foo`, `&mut &Foo`, `Foo`, `&Foo`, `&mut Foo`.

This is because there is the chain of dereferencing `&Foo` → `Foo`, and for each `U` in this chain we insert also `&U` and `&mut U`.

My intuition is confirmed by the fact that the following code also works, without any explicit dereference.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Foo();

trait MyInto<T> {
    fn my_into(self) -> T;
}

impl MyInto<&'static str> for Foo {
    fn my_into(self) -> &'static str {
        "<Foo as MyInto>::my_into"
    }
}

fn vec_my_into<F: Copy + MyInto<T>, T>(slice: &[F]) -> Vec<T> {
    slice.iter().map(|x| x.my_into()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let array = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()];
    let my_vec = vec_my_into(&array);
    println!("{:?}", my_vec);
}
```

Here `x: &Foo` is implicitly dereferenced in order to call the method `<Foo as MyInto<&'static str>>::my_into`.

## A smaller example

Given the above definitions of `Foo` and `MyInto`, the code

```rust
let result: &str = (&Foo()).my_into()
```

works, but

```rust
let result: &str = (&Foo()).into()
```

fails to compile with the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: std::convert::From<&Foo>` is not satisfied
  --> src/bin/into.rs:34:33
   |
34 |     let result: &str = (&Foo()).into();
   |                                 ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&Foo>` is not implemented for `&str`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<&str>` for `&Foo`
```

Comment: Again unrelated to your question, but `struct Foo();` and `Foo()` can just be `struct Foo;` and `Foo`. Helps to avoid mistakes thinking it's a regular function.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks, I didn't know (now I see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#unit-like-structs-without-any-fields)

Comment: More relevant to your question, [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust performs method lookup exatly as you describe, and it immediately finds a candidate for `.into()` – the [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#implementors)

```
impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
where
    U: From<T>,
{
    fn into(self) -> U {
        U::from(self)
    }
}
```

This implementation fulfils all the requirements for candidate methods – it is visible, in scope and defined for type `&Foo`, since it is defined for *any* type `T`. Once the compiler has picked this candidate, it notices that the trait bounds on `U` are not satisfied, and issues the error you see.

The situation for `MyInto` is completely different, because you don't provide a blanket implementation based on `From`. If you do, you will get the same error.

It could be argued that the compiler should skip the blanket implementation if the trait bounds are not satisfied, and move on with the list of candidate types until it finds a better fit. The language specification is actually not completely clear on that point, but from the error we see it is clear what the compiler actually does.

Comment: I expect it to be Solved by Chalk™.

Comment: @Shepmaster Whenever I see any type inference or constraint solver weirdness, I have the same hope, but I actually don't know what the exact differences will be, or how many years it will take since it lands in rustc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This would not happen if there were unsatisfied trait bounds on `T`, right? I mean, in that case the implementation would be skipped and the search for a suitable method would continue. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, after inspecting the compiler output, it would appear that the `Into` implementation actually just calls a method of the trait `From`. What it's looking for is `std::collections::From<&Foo> for &str`. Therefore, if we implement that trait, the compiler will indeed find our function, and execute it.

Using the following declarations:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Foo();

impl std::convert::From<&Foo> for &str {
    fn from(f: &Foo) -> &'static str {
        "A &str"// This could be replaced with an actual implementation
    }
}
```

Your code works as you wanted:

```
let result: &str = (&Foo()).into();// No compiler errors.
```

The original code you wanted does work, and it isn't actually hard to implement.