# What means Into in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm reading this piece of code:

```
pub fn ip_addrs<T>(mut self, ip_addrs: T) -> Self
        where T: Into<ManagedSlice<'c, IpCidr>>
    {
```

`T` must be of type `Into`. However, I cannot understand what `Into` does by reading its definition. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html) and [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html) are two traits specifying protocols for converting between types (without failure). That is if `A` implements `Into<B>`, you can always convert an `A` to a `B` and it will never fail.

Here it's used such that you can give this function anything which is *convertible* to a `ManagedSlice`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812530/when-should-i-implement-stdconvertfrom-vs-stdconvertinto