# Why am I required to "cover" T in `impl ForeignTrait<LocalType> for T` [E0210]

Tags: rust, traits

Today I ran into a pretty strange error message that I'm having a hard time understanding. Consider this easy map-entry-like struct:

```rust
struct Entry<K, V> {
    key: K,
    value: V
}
```

Now, I want to implement all the `std::cmp` traits between `Entry<K, V>` with itself and with just `K`. Let's focus on `PartialEq` for now. These two implementations work just fine:

```rust
impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq for Entry<K, V> { /* ... */ }
impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq<K> for Entry<K, V> { /* ... */ }
```

But the last one gives me a hard time ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9e5cd57c4845a451c2546e1b214d4df))

```rust
impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq<Entry<K, V>> for K {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Entry<K, V>) -> bool {
        self.eq(&other.key)
    }
}
```

The error message, as far as I can understand it, claims I'd be using a non-local type as the first parameter of the foreign trait. However, `Entry` ist defined locally in the same file.

> error[[E0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0210)]: type parameter `K` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Entry<K, V>`)
>
> ```
> --> src/lib.rs:6:6
>   |
> 6 | impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq<Entry<K, V>> for K {
>   |      ^ type parameter `K` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Entry<K, V>`)
>   |
> ```
>
> **note:** implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which is it implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type 
> **note:** in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last

Can someone explain why I am getting this error message, what the error and especially *uncovered* means and why this implementation is disallowed?

Comment: See also [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster I know what a conflicting implementation is, I ran into that before. However, I am getting a completely different error message, so I don't understand how the question you linked applies here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message is pretty poor but reading the full description of [E0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0210) very carefully gives at least an explanation as to what's going on:

> Consider an impl:
>
> ```
> impl<P1, ..., Pm> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0 { ... }
> ```
>
> where `P1, ..., Pm` are the type parameters of the `impl` and `T0, ..., Tn` are types. One of the types `T0, ..., Tn` must be a local type (this is another orphan rule, see the explanation for [E0117](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0117)).
>
> Both of the following must be true:
>
> 1. At least one of the types `T0..=Tn` must be a local type. Let `Ti` be the first such type.
> 2. No uncovered type parameters `P1..=Pm` may appear in `T0..Ti` (excluding `Ti`).

Now, looking back at the implementation in question, it is declared as

```
impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq<Entry<K, V>> for K // error
```

So gives a mapping of `P1=K, P2=V` and `T0=K, T1=Entry<K, V>`, `Ti` is `T1` and therefore the error message is triggered. *Covering* is as easy as putting it into a one-element tuple, so this syntax is totally fine:

```
impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq<Entry<K, V>> for (K,) // ok
```

Generally, *covering* a type can be done by placing it into a tuple (`(K,)`) or using it as a type parameter (`SomeType<K>`), but **not** using a reference (`&K`) or a box (`Box<K>`).

An understandable and reasonable explanation for this is then only given in the implementing [RFC 2451](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.html), which recommended this to be part of the error message:

> Rust's orphan rule always permits an impl if either the trait or the type being implemented are local to the current crate. Therefore, we can't allow `impl<T> ForeignTrait<LocalTypeCrateA> for T`, because it might conflict with another crate writing `impl<T> ForeignTrait<T> for LocalTypeCrateB`, which we will always permit.

I wish rustc would've adopted that error message rather than spitting out the cryptic one it currently does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the other way around:

```
impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq<K> for Entry<K, V> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &K) -> bool {
        self.key.eq(&other)
    }
}
```

As for why your direction does not work: Imagine someone defines a `struct` that can be compared to *anything*:

```
struct K;

impl<V> PartialEq<V> for K { // V could be anything (including your struct Entry)
    fn eq(&self, other: &V) -> bool {
        true
    }
}
```

Now, there would be conflicting `impl`s for `K` and your `Entry`.

Comment: Ok I can see that those implementations would collide but I don't think that rustc limits it in general. At least I don't understand why there is no such constraint for the `Into` trait nowadays (I know this changed in recent rust versions, before which you always had to implement `From`): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a8f84c8538e2a8f421be218873a69d6

Comment: @msrd0 *before which you always had to implement `From`* —  you never had to implement `From` (see [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423)). Perhaps you mean something more specific?

Comment: @Shepmaster _always_ is probably wrong here, I should've written _in most cases_. I am referring to the changes landed in rust 1.41 where implementations on foreign traits were relaxed. Read the [release notes](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/01/30/Rust-1.41.0.html#relaxed-restrictions-when-implementing-traits), they even use the exact same example of `From` and `Into`

Comment: Also, I might be wrong but the `PartialEq` trait calls its optional parameter `Rhs` (right-hand side) so I assume that the order of comparision (`a == b` vs `b == a`) determines which trait implementation is used, so I assume I need both implementations to have both equality comparisons above working