# What exactly is the requirement for "covering" a type & why does a single element tuple satisfy it?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, trait-objects

Assuming the following code is present

```rust
use core::any::Any;

enum Value {
    Any(Box<dyn Any>),
    Other, // placeholder, this code is adapted from mine
}
```

This code raises a diagnostic that I can't quite understand

```rust
impl<T: Any> TryFrom<Value> for T {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(val: Value) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if let Value::Any(any) = val {
            if let Ok(down) = any.downcast::<T>() {
                Ok(*down)
            } else {
                Err("incorrect type")
            }
        } else { Err("not an any") }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let res: Result<usize, &'static str> = Value::Any(Box::new(1usize)).try_into();
    dbg!(res);
}
```

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Value`)
 --> src/main.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl<T: Any> TryFrom<Value> for T {
  |      ^ type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Value`)
  |
  = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
  = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last
```

I still don't quite understand what "must be covered by another type" means, nor "when it appears before the first local type".

However, if I modify the impl signature to target a single-element tuple containing T, the impl does not raise an error, and the code functions correctly:

```rust
impl<T: Any> TryFrom<Value> for (T,) {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(val: Value) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if let Value::Any(any) = val {
            if let Ok(down) = any.downcast::<T>() {
                Ok((*down,))
            } else {
                Err("incorrect type")
            }
        } else { Err("not an any") }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let res: Result<(usize,), &'static str> = Value::Any(Box::new(1usize)).try_into();
    dbg!(res);
}
```

What purpose does the single-element tuple actually serve?

([Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b70e3885da17d15d42f3aac1cf4cc24b))

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131661/4909009 ?

Comment: @Kendas I have, except it still doesn't explain to me how (T,) solves the issue, it's not defined in my crate, as it's a primitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC 2451](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.html):

> Covered Type: A type which appears as a parameter to another type. For example, `T` is uncovered, but the `T` in `Vec<T>` is covered. This is only relevant for type parameters.

It is important to note that the type `T` *does not equal* the tuple type `(T,)`. `(T,)` can be considered equivalent to a hypothetical generic newtype/tuple struct `struct Tuple1<T>(T)` defined in the standard library crate `std`. With this analogy, `impl<T: Any> TryFrom<Value> for (T,)` is equivalent to `impl<T: Any> TryFrom<Value> for std::Tuple1<T>`.

Note that the covering type (in this case the single element tuple type, or in our analogy `Tuple1`) *need not be defined locally* in the same crate. To put it simply, consider an `impl<T> ForeignTrait<LocalType> for ForeignType<T>`:

1. The covering type `ForeignType` has already been defined. So:
2. The only way `ForeignTrait<LocalType>` can be implemented for
   `ForeignType<T>` outside of the current crate is through a generic
   `impl <S, T> ForeignTrait<S> for ForeignType<T>` (where `S` covers
   `LocalType`).
3. Because of these rules, an `impl <S, T> ForeignTrait<S> for ForeignType<T>` that covers `ForeignTrait<LocalType>` is only possible in the crate declaring `ForeignType`.

Hence it is impossible for a conflicting implementation of `ForeignTrait<LocalType>` to exist for `ForeignType<T>` outside of a) the local crate and b) the crate declaring `ForeignType`, and so the `impl` is allowed. The RFC [discusses this](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.html#concrete-orphan-rules) in more detail.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still not entirely sure why implementing something for a single tuple (which as you've said is equivalent to a newtype defined in core/std) doesn't violate orphaning rules.

Comment: The whole point of the orphaning rules is to guarantee the absence of multiple implementations of a trait for a type. In my example above, let `ForeignTrait = TryFrom`, `LocalType = Value` and `ForeignType<T> = Tuple1<T>`. Outside of our crate, `TryFrom<Value>` can only be implemented for `Tuple1<T>` via a generic `TryFrom<R>` (because of the orphaning rules). Because of the same orphaning rules, this generic `impl<R, T> TryFrom<R> for Tuple1<T>` can only be done in `std`. So, if `std` does not contain that generic impl, we know no one but we can implement `TryFrom<Value>` for `Tuple1<T>`.