# How can I make a type that de/serializes any other type that implements Serialized + DeserializeOwned?

Tags: rust, traits, serde

edit: I would still like to re-open this, so I can post an answer for anyone searching.  The answer is to use inherent methods.  Chayim-Friedman pointed me in the right direction, and now here is a [working playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

I would like to point out again to editors that my question is not about From and Into, trait covering etc.  Those are impl details of my first failed attempt.  My question is about making a type that can de/serialize any other type.  And Chayim's answer is the correct one, which has nothing to do with From/Into and trait covering.  So *if* this is a dup, then it is a dup of something else.  Anyway, I hope the above playground helps someone.

edit:  I voted to re-open this. No solution to my problem is provided in the question that this supposedly duplicates. If what I am trying to do is simply not possible, then that would be a good answer.

At least such an answer highlights rust's limitations and inherent asymmetry in this area. Further this q is not a dup because the linked question only discusses the first error, not my second attempt, which deals with `Into`

Lastly, this particular impl attempt was just my first attempts to solve the general problem posed in my question:

**How can I make a type that de/serializes any other type that implements Serialized + DeserializeOwned?**

If there is some other solution, I would love to know about it.   Else it seems that is impossible in Rust, yes?

---

I tried to make a blanket impl for `Serialize` and `DeserializeOwned`.    It works for `Serialize`, but `DeserializeOwned` gives me problems.

Here's what I tried.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize, de::DeserializeOwned};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Bytes(pub Vec<u8>);

impl<T> From<Bytes> for T
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    #[inline]
    fn from(value: Bytes) -> Self {
        Self(bincode::deserialize(&value.0).expect("should have deserialized bytes into T"))
    }
}


impl<T> From<T> for Bytes
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    #[inline]
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        Bytes(bincode::serialize(&value).expect("should have serialized T into bytes"))
    }
}



fn main() {
    let bytes = Bytes::from(10u64);
    println!("bytes: {:?}", bytes);

    let num: u64 = bytes.into();
    println!("num: {}", num);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

and I get this error.

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Bytes`)
  --> src/main.rs:13:6
   |
13 | impl<T: DeserializeOwned> From<Bytes> for T
   |      ^ type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Bytes`)
   |
   = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
   = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0210`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

I then tried using `Into` instead of `From` to avoid the "covered by another type" error.

```rust
impl<T> Into<T> for Bytes
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    #[inline]
    fn into(value: Self) -> T {
        Self(bincode::deserialize(&value.0).expect("should have deserialized bytes into T"))
    }
}
```

[PlayGround](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

Then I get a different error.

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Into<_>` for type `Bytes`
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | / impl<T> Into<T> for Bytes
14 | | where
15 | |     T: DeserializeOwned,
   | |________________________^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
             where U: From<T>;

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

There is an unpleasant asymmetry in the fact that it works just fine one direction (serialization) but not the other (deserialization).

Is there a solution?

Comment: I voted to re-open this.  No solution to my problem is provided in the question that this supposedly duplicates.   If what I am trying to do is simply not possible, then that would be a good answer. 
At least it highlights rust's limitations and inherent asymmetry in this area.  Further this q is not a dup because the linked question only discusses the first attempt+error, not my second, which deals with Into.

Comment: You can only do that with inherent methods.

Comment: Ok, that seems an interesting lead.  I'm not sure how inherent methods relate to this though, or would solve the problem.   I just want to get my bytes serialized and deserialized for all types able to do so.

Comment: After reading through your question, I agree this is a duplicate question, but the question being linked does a poor job of explaining why the issue occurs and how it is fixed. The usage of `serde` is not really a important since the root of the issue is just the context of why this error occurs. I think it would be more accurate to say this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63119000/5987669.

Comment: It may be easier to think about this from the perspective of a user working with your crate. Lets say that I made a type `Buffer` that worked like `Bytes`, but with some added functionality. If I implement `From<Bytes>`, it would prevent me from implementing `Deserialize` for `Buffer` since there would then be 2 competing implementations of `From<Bytes>` for `Buffer`. These idiosyncrasies compound leading to an ecosystem full of edge cases for specific types. This may improve in the future though as more RFCs such as min-specialization get stabilized.

Comment: Just have a method `from_any<T>(value: &T) -> Bytes` and `into_any<T>(&self) -> T`. Nothing fancy or special.

Comment: Thank-you Chayim-Friedman.   That solves my problem.   The funny thing is, I had already made fn with exactly those signatures, but was not utilizing them properly in my other types.  Your suggestion made it click for me, and now all is working.