# Is there a Rust equivalent to C++'s operator bool() to convert a struct into a boolean?

Tags: rust

In C++, we can overload `operator bool()` to convert a struct to `bool`:

```cpp
struct Example {
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    Example a;
    if (a) { /* some work  */ }
}
```

Can we do something simple (and elegant) in Rust so to:

```rust
pub struct Example {}

fn main() {
    let k = Example {};
    if k {
        // some work
    }
}
```

Comment: Another fine example why C++ is such a "dangerous" language. Even if `Example` is not a boolean type, it is used as such. So the real conversion is hidden, and from the source it is **not** clear what is meant. :-(

Comment: What is your use case for this? Is this really a type conversion, or do you want to assign a "truthiness" to a data type, e.g. `false` means empty container and `true` means non-empty? The idiomatic way to do this in Rust depends on your actual use case.

Comment: While that may be "simple", I'd argue that it's *not* "elegant". What does `if k` even mean? You're better off implementing a specific method that returns a boolean and calling that -- eg `if k.has_data()`

Answer (score 11):

There's no direct equivalent of `operator bool()`. A close alternative would be to implement `From` (which will also implement `Into`) and call the conversion explicitly:

```rust
pub struct Example;

impl From<Example> for bool {
    fn from(_other: Example) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let k = Example;
    if k.into() {
        // some work
    }
}
```

This will take ownership of `Example`, meaning you can't use `k` after it's been converted. You could implement it for a reference (`impl From<&Example> for bool`) but then the call site becomes uglier (`(&k).into()`).

I'd probably **avoid** using `From` / `Into` for this case. Instead, I'd create a predicate method on the type. This will be more readable and can take `&self`, allowing you to continue using the value.

See also:

- [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423)

Comment: [The API guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#conversions-use-the-standard-traits-from-asref-asmut-c-conv-traits) state that `Into` should never be implemented. Since this is a rather highly voted answer, it should probably be implemented with the idiomatic `From<Example> for bool`?

Comment: @sebpuetz a good point. It's _less_ needed since a few Rust versions back, but we still use `From` for consistency.

Comment: It's not only for consistency. Implementing `From<T> for U` gives you `Into<U> for T` for free because of the blanket impl, while implementing `Into<U> for T` directly doesn't give you a `From` impl.

Comment: @SvenMarnach my point is that relatively recent Rust versions removed the entire reason that both `From` and `Into` existed in the first place. If the standard library were designed today, there would only be `Into`. That wasn't true in Rust 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

Rust does not have C++'s implicit type conversion via operator overloading. The closest means of implicit conversion is through a `Deref` impl, which provides a reference of a different type.

What *is* possible, albeit not necessarily idiomatic, is to implement the not operator `!` so that it returns a boolean value, and perform the not operation twice when needed.

```rust
use std::ops::Not;

pub struct Example;

impl Not for Example {
    type Output = bool;
    
    fn not(self) -> bool { false }
}

fn main() {
    let k = Example;
    if !!k {
        println!("OK!");
    } else {
        println!("WAT");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ca73cd81b0a038e57b1875931f739d5)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options, but I'd go for one of these:

### `Into<bool>` (`From<Example>`)

If your trait conceptually represents a `bool`, but maybe with some extra metadata, you can implement `From<Example>` for `bool`:

```rust
impl From<Example> for bool {
    fn from(e: Example) {
        // perform the conversion
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = Example { /* ... */ };
    if x.into() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### Custom method

If your type doesn't really represent a boolean value, I'd usually go for an explicit method:

```rust
impl Example {
    fn has_property() -> bool { /* ... */ }
}
```

This makes it more obvious what the intent is, for example, if you implemented `From<User> for bool`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let user = User { /* ... */  };

    if user.into() {
        // when does this code get run??
    }

    // compared to
    if user.logged_in() {
        // much clearer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [`std::ops::Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) with the `bool` type. If you do that, you have to call `*k` to get the boolean.

This is not recommended though, according to the Rust documentation:

> On the other hand, the rules regarding Deref and DerefMut were designed specifically to accommodate smart pointers. Because of this, Deref should only be implemented for smart pointers to avoid confusion.

```rust
struct Example {}

impl std::ops::Deref for Example {
    type Target = bool;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &true
    }
}

fn main() {
    let k = Example {};
    if *k {
        // some work
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8612057785b6fc38fa3b10545828848)

Comment: The OP's type does not have a boolean field.